# How to format complex mathematical expressions?

Tags: c#, coding-style

This might not be the place for this, and if so I do apologize and ask that you point me in the direction where it may be appropriate for me to get an answer. This is a problem I run into when I code alot.

```
new Vector2(parent.Coordinates.X + (Position + parent.Prompt.Length - parent.visibilityIndex) * parent.font.Width, parent.Coordinates.Y);
```

That's quite a line! So I'll break it up into two:

```
new Vector2(parent.Coordinates.X + (Position + parent.Prompt.Length - parent.visibilityIndex) * parent.font.Width, 
            parent.Coordinates.Y);
```

That's a little better, but still way too long. Anywhere else I try to break up the line seems arbitrary and to serve to obfuscate the code further. Am I wrong? What do you do? Again, I apologize if this is the wrong place for this as I am not sure.

Comment: Might be closed as either off-topic or non-constructive, I'm not sure. Maybe it's a suitable coding-style question for [programmers.se]?  Or maybe it's just too much of a low-level detail?

Comment: Yeah, it should be on programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is subjective, but in this case I would split it out into separate variables.

```
var fontWidth = parent.font.Width;
var index = parent.visibilityIndex;
var offset = (Position + parent.Prompt.Length - index) * fontWidth;
return new Vector2(parent.Coordinates.X + offset, parent.Coordinates.Y);
```

Split it up in whichever way makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Ed S. uses quite a few variables, you could accomplish the same with less.

```
double x = (Position + parent.Prompt.Length - parent.visibilityIndex);
x *= parent.font.Width;
x += parent.Coordinates.X;
new Vector2(x, parent.Coordinates.Y);
```

Comment: Haha, yes, those two extra stack allocated variables are expensive!  Show me when it becomes a bottleneck and then I'll agree with you.  Also, I'd ask you to take a look at the disassembly before making that claim.

Comment: I would rather optimize for readability than for stack memory in a 3 liner piece of code representing a calculation in a modern high level language. The compiled code may well be optimized for you anyway. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - famous quote!

Answer (score 1):

I typically just set a column guide at column 80 and break on the first operator I find before the guide:

```
new Vector2(parent.Coordinates.X + (Position + parent.Prompt.Length -          |
    parent.visibilityIndex) * parent.font.Width, parent.Coordinates.Y);        |
```

It's possibly not the most readable approach, and sometimes needs some tweaking (particularly when having to deal with `ridiculouslyLongVariableOrMethodNames`), but it does the job for me. YMMV.

Comment: I add the column guide as well, but in this example I now have to hunt for the comma to see where the first argument ends.  I can't say it's any more readable than the original example.

Comment: @Ed: I can't say I disagree - like I said in the answer, it definitely *isn't* the most readable approach. That said, it can potentially be tweaked to highlight the comma - for example by breaking on the comma too (despite the fact that a break isn't needed).